# How to use NaCl Encryption for Threema-API in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, nonce, nacl-cryptography

I want to write a C# Threema API for an internal tool.

Here is the API:
https://gateway.threema.ch/en/developer/api

It says, for the end-to-end encryption there has to be a NaCl encryption, when I understand it right - The API is a webAPI which needs:

```
[nonce] nonce used for encryption (24 bytes, hex encoded)
[box] encrypted message data (max. 4000 bytes, hex encoded)
```

So how to encrypt this data? Of course I can have a 24byte long hex encoded string generated for the nonce, but how to encryt a text with that nonce in c#?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime Threema has provided a .NET version of the Gateway SDK: [Threema Message API .NET](https://gateway.threema.ch/de/developer/sdk-net)

Otherwise, you should look into the libsodium library which is used for encryption of the messages in Threema. There is for example the [libsodium-net](https://github.com/adamcaudill/libsodium-net) which provides all the tools needed for encryption.